# Print a database table and colour the parent row basing on its child colour

Tags: php, jquery, html-table

A PHP page must show the content of a database's table. In another table, there is the value I will use to print the row accordingly and show as a child.

```
$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT *,'SENT' as direction FROM table1 WHERE identification LIKE '%$identification%' AND expedition LIKE '$expedition' order by date DESC LIMIT '$limit' ");
```

This, inside a WHILE, will print this kind of table:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {

    $sql2 = pg_query($conn, " SELECT quantity FROM expedition WHERE identification='$row[2]' ");
    $row2 = pg_fetch_row($sql2);
    $color="white";
    if ($row2[0] == "-1") { $color="red";}
    if ($row2[0] == "1") { $color="green";}
    if ($row2[0] == "0") { $color="grey";}

echo "<tr bgcolor=\"$color\">
    <td><button class=\"btn btn-info\" type=\"button\" data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-target=\"#$row[2]\">+</button></td>
    <td>row[0]</td>
    <td>row[1]</td>
    <td>row[2]</td>
    <td>row[3]</td>
    <td>row[4]</td>
    <td>...and more</td>
    </tr>";

echo "<tr><td colspan=9><div style=\"background-color:$color\" id=\"$row[2]\" class=\"collapse\">$row2[0]</div></td></tr> ";
```

I am using bootstrap to add a button that, once clicked, will open a hidden row with the content of `$sql2`. Query that I will print straight after the `</tr>`.

Notice the 1st query as `row[]` and the second query as `row2[]`.

**The problem:**
If the second query contains more than 1 result and in all cases identification is not a PK (therefore there could be more), I am not able to print for each row the colour of its childs.

1. *I need to extend the second query to manage a WHILE loop, in order to extract, through identification, all the values of its parent*.
2. *IF, sql2 contains -1 or 1 or 0, the parent and itself must be painted accordingly*.
3. *IF, sql2 contains different values, both of them must be painted red (as error)*.

The obvious choice would be to move the SQL2 at the end of the first WHILE, in this case I can have SQL2 with all the records I want.
just like using arrays or the FOR structure.

Stays though the fact that moving the code would not allow me to print all the rows, because html is wrote already.

In this case I believe I'd need Jquery to highlight the values once they are written already.
I do not know a thing of Jquery and I'd appreciate any suggestion or help.

Attached a image to show what I achieved, the green bar only contain 1 child as the code above. Forgive the ugly interface!
[image]